# Inserting an Equation

Tags: equations, formatting, amsmath

Im very new to tex and have problems with equation.
I have to implement following equation.[image: equation]

Could somebody be so kind and help me with the syntax?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried so far and where you're getting stuck. Aside: Have you studied [The not so short introduction to LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort-letter.pdf) by Tobi Oetiker et al?

Answer (score 2):

TeX is meant to type such equation, you should have posted the part you managed to type.
You will need `\underset{}{}` `\left\lbarce` `\right\rbrace` and of course `\sum^{}_{}`
If you're very new to `TeX` you must consider studying these macros.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\underset{\left\lbrace w_{i,t}\right\rbrace^{N_t}_{i=1}}{\mathrm{max}}~
%
\mathrm{E}_t\left[u\left(r_{p,t+1}\right)\right]=
%
\mathrm{E}_t\left[u\left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}w_{i,t}r_{i,t+1}\right)\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to replace `\underset{\left\lbrace w_{i,t}\right\rbrace^{N_t}_{i=1}}{\mathrm{max}}` with `\max_{ \{w_{i,t}\}_{i=1}^{N_t} }`.

Comment: @Mico You're right, it's way better than what I wrote.